# Spring Config Server - Cannot log to database - NullPointerException DataSource

Tags: java, spring, log4j2

I want to migrate a Java Spring project from hard coded application.properties to Spring Cloud Config. The implementation was no problem but now Log4j2 does not work properly. Usually the log outputs should be written to a database table. The configuration is done via a log4j2.xml file and a LoggerFactory class (JDBCConnectionFactoryForLog4J2).

As I understood it correctly, Log4j2 is already started before the configuration request at the Config Server is started. Thus, according to my understanding, the LoggerFactory class is obsolete. But unfortunately I don't really understand now, how I can set up the configuration of Log4j2 so that the database connection can only happen after the configuration query.

log4j2.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p ${hostName} --- [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex
        </Property>
        <Property name="JDBC_LEVEL">INFO</Property>
        <Property name="CONSOLE_FILE_LEVEL">INFO</Property>
        <Property name="LOG_DIR">.</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="FileAppender" fileName="${LOG_DIR}/service_registry.log" filePattern="${LOG_DIR}/service_registry-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
        </RollingFile>
        <JDBC name="MySQLDatabase" tableName="logs">
            <ConnectionFactory class="eu.arrowhead.common.log4j2.JDBCConnectionFactoryForLog4J2" method="getConnection" />
            <Column name="log_id" pattern="%u" />
            <Column name="entry_date" isEventTimestamp="true" />
            <Column name="logger" pattern="%logger" />
            <Column name="log_level" pattern="%level" />
            <Column name="message" pattern="%m" />
            <Column name="exception" pattern="%throwable " />
            <ThresholdFilter level="${JDBC_LEVEL}" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </JDBC>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="WARN">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" /> <!-- comment out this one in production environment -->
            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender" />
        </Root>
        <AsyncLogger name="eu.arrowhead" level="${JDBC_LEVEL}" additivity="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="MySQLDatabase" />
        </AsyncLogger>
        <Logger name="eu.arrowhead.common" level="${CONSOLE_FILE_LEVEL}" additivity="true"></Logger>
        <Logger name="eu.arrowhead.core" level="${CONSOLE_FILE_LEVEL}" additivity="true"></Logger>      
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

LoggerFactory Class

```java
public class JDBCConnectionFactoryForLog4J2 {


    //=================================================================================================
    // members
    private static Properties props;
    private static DataSource dataSource;

    static {
        try {
            init();
        } catch (final IOException ex) {
            // this class' purpose to configure logging so in case of exceptions we can't use logging
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); //NOSONAR no logging at this point
            ex.printStackTrace(); //NOSONAR no logging at this point
        }
    }

    //=================================================================================================
    // methods

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        if (dataSource == null) {
            final HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
            config.setJdbcUrl(props.getProperty(CoreCommonConstants.DATABASE_URL));
            config.setUsername(props.getProperty(CoreCommonConstants.DATABASE_USER));
            config.setPassword(props.getProperty(CoreCommonConstants.DATABASE_PASSWORD));
            config.setDriverClassName(props.getProperty(CoreCommonConstants.DATABASE_DRIVER_CLASS));
            
            dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
        }
        
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }
    
    //=================================================================================================
    // assistant methods

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private static void init() throws IOException {
        InputStream propStream = null;
        final File propertiesFile = new File(CoreCommonConstants.APPLICATION_PROPERTIES);

        if (!propertiesFile.exists()) {
            propStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(CoreCommonConstants.APPLICATION_PROPERTIES);
        } else {
            propStream = new FileInputStream(propertiesFile);
        }
        
        final Properties temp = new Properties();
        temp.load(propStream);

        props = temp;
    }
    
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private JDBCConnectionFactoryForLog4J2() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```